# Matlab 'count to 10' basic game exercise?

Tags: matlab

I received this question and am at a standstill. This is an intro course so we should really only be using basics and while/for/if-else loops.  Here is the exercise:

> In this exercise you are required to implement a simple two player counting game. The game starts by setting the count to 0. The two players should take alternative turns selecting between the numbers 1 and 2.
>   In each turn the number the current player selects gets added to the count. The player who reaches a value 10 or larger wins the game. The program should check for input correctness.
>   The image below has a sample run.

Here is the sample run given in the assignment, and what I have so far.

> [image][image]

I have now gotten a little further as seen here:

[image]

However I don't understand how to make it alternate between Player 1 and 2, or how to display the winner.  All it does is add the value and ask again at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some working code, but if this is a homework assignment you really should try your best to solve it yourself. I will give you a hint though:
If you have a variable called `player` that is either 1 or 2, then

```
player = 2 / player;
```

will always give you the other number; if player = 1, after that, player = 2, then player = 1, ...etc.

I would also suggest that you check the input immediately, instead of how you're doing it:

```
while (~(choice == 1 | choice == 2))
    choice = input('Enter 1 or 2: ');
end
```

Once you have something working I will be happy to share my full code if you would like it.

Comment: I have this so far - it's pretty much almost done, and the part that is cut off the command window is the exact same as the given sample.  Thanks very much for the tip on the Player switching.

However I just can't figure out how to notify the winner - since the player command switches it, I can't just pull that variable.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, your while loop will exit as soon as the sum > 10. That means that the last `player` that entered a number is the loser, right? Just switch the `player` counter one more time and display it as `fprintf('Winner is %i',player);`  EDIT: I misunderstood, the _winner_ is the `player` that knocks the sum over 10. You should be able to just use `player` without switching again, then, because the while loop will exit after the winner's input.

Comment: Yup, I'd done that already and it gets the end result, but the problem is that it still leaves that annoying "Player 1" right before it since technically it's going through the if statement and switching it and printing it.  Any ideas?

http://imgur.com/kw586VJ

Comment: You should move that print to the inside of your while loop, and generate the "Player X:" string on the fly by `fprintf('Player %i',player)`

Comment: I think you're close enough. Here's how I did it: http://gist.github.com/athingunique/fe83f554b989b9efaf82

Comment: well if I do that, then won't the while loop always print the winner regardless?  For example: http://imgur.com/7i8F4O9

Comment: I meant to move the prompting print statement into the while loop, not the winner statement. See my gist above.

Comment: Ohhhhhh okay.  What purpose does choice = -1 solve?  Is it just to assign a value so matlab recognizes it?

And I also have to make it prompt me when an incorrect value is given.  That's just a simple if-else within the inner while loop correct?

Comment: Essentially, yes, it is there to make sure that the value of `choice` is **not** 1 or 2 so that we make sure to prompt the user at least once to input a value. This is just good practice. It's not strictly necessary in MATLAB, but could be in other non garbage collected languages where you could get a random value when the variable is unassigned. Displaying an error when the value is incorrect will require some modifications to the inner loop. I'll leave that to you to figure out. EDIT: also, please accept the answer if I've helped you!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it's much appreciated!  Guess these things just come with practice.  And sorry about that - first time on Stack.